# How to filter same array of names multiple times in tableView with one button?

Tags: swift

I'm working with JSON and the challenge is to make an app that contains facts about countries.
Currently, I'm making a filter button to preview a certain country. But I can use it only once and if I try again I get an empty tableView. So I wanted to make a filter button that will iterate through countries every time without having to make reload button which I would have to click to reload all countries and then tap the filter again.
MyCode:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var countries = [Countries]()
    var countriesF = [Countries] ()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Filter", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filtrate))
        tableView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        let urlString : String
        urlString = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
                parse(json: data)
                countriesF = countries
                return
                
            }
        }
    }
    func parse(json: Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        if let country = try? decoder.decode([Countries].self, from: json){
            countries = country
        }
    }
    @objc func filtrate (){
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Find", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField()
        let filter = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default){
            [weak self, weak ac] _ in
            guard let word = ac?.textFields?[0].text else {return}
            self?.submit(for: word)
            
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        ac.addAction(filter)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancle", style: .cancel))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        
    }
    func submit(for filter: String){
        countriesF = countriesF.filter{
            $0.name.contains(filter)//ako je rec sadrzana u imenu...
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        countriesF.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
        let country = countriesF[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = country.name
        return cell
        
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewControler{
            
            vc.detailItem = countriesF[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
countriesF = countriesF.filter{...
```

filters itself to *death*. You have to filter the full array

```
countriesF = countries.filter{...
```

And never ever load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`. It blocks the thread. Use an asynchronous way.